# Promise dependency resolution order in angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, promise, angular-ui-router

I have set up a top-level controller that is instantiated only when a promise (returned by a `Config` factory) is successfully resolved. That promise basically downloads the Web app configuration, with RESTful endpoints and so on.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'views/_index.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: {
      config: 'Config'
    }
  });
```

This setup allows me to kind-of assert that the configuration is properly loaded before any lower controller gets a chance to use it.

Now I need to inject, in a deeper nested controller, another `factory` that uses `Config` and only works when it is resolved (look at it like a `$resource` wrapper that needs some Web service URLs). If I do:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.bottom.page', {
    url: '/bottom/page',
    templateUrl: 'views/_a_view.html',
    controller: 'BottomLevelCtrl',
    resolve: {
      TheResource: 'MyConfigDependingResource'
    }
  });
```

it looks like the `resolve` evaluation order does not follow the controller hierarchy from top to bottom, but from bottom to top, therefore:

1. `app.bottom.page` is entered
2. `ui-router` attempts to resolve `MyConfigDependingResource`, but the injection fails,
   because `Config` has never been initialized
3. The `ui-router` resolution stops because of an error (without even throwing `Error`s, but that's another issue), and `Config` is never initialized by the top level controller

Why is `ui-router` resolving dependencies in a reverse order? How can I easily resolve my `TheResource` object **after** the  top level `MainCtrl` has resolved `Config` (without relying on `$inject`, of course)?

**UPDATE**: from [this plnkr's log](http://plnkr.co/edit/LmDKZ1nhyGwqDF19Ckhb?p=preview) you can see that the top level `resolve` is attempted only after the nested controller has started its own resolving process.

Comment: The parent should be resolved first. Can you share a plunker?

Comment: There you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/LmDKZ1nhyGwqDF19Ckhb?p=preview.

As you can see from the console `$log` information, the first Config request is made because the `MyConfigDependingResource` is resolved by the nested controller, before the `Config` is resolved in the root controller.

Comment: @IlanFrumer have you tried executing the plunker?

Answer (score 61):

Similarly to @Kasper Lewau's answer, one may specify a dependency on resolves withing a single state. If one of your resolves depends on one or more resolve properties from the same resolve block. In my case `checkS` relies on two other resolves

```
.state('stateofstate', {
    url: "/anrapasd",
    templateUrl: "views/anrapasd.html",
    controller: 'SteofsteCtrl',
    resolve: {
        currU: function(gamMag) {
            return gamMag.checkWifi("jabadabadu")
        },
        userC: function(gamUser, $stateParams) {
            return gamUser.getBipi("oink")
        },
        checkS: ['currU', 'userC', 'gamMag', function(currU, userC, gamMag) {
            return gamMag.check(currU, userC);
        }]
    }
})
```

---

**PS: **Check the "Resolves" section of the [following document](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c) for more details about the inner-workings of `resolve`.

Comment: I think it's pretty much an anwear for resolve order, cause you can chain those like that.

Comment: not sure how this works for anyone... angular thinks that currU , etc. are services and tries to resolve them but is unable to

Comment: u saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Have the same doubt as @KingOfHypocrites 
I would get currU and userC as undefined, any answer ?

Answer (score 16):

Resolve objects run in parallel, and as such doesn't follow a certain hierarchy. 
However, nested resolves are possible by defining a higher order resolve object as a dependency to your secondary resolves.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('topState', {
    url: '/',
    resolve: {
      mainResolveObj: ['$someService', function ($someService) {
        return 'I am needed elsewhere!';
      }]
    }
  })
  .state('topState.someOtherState', {
    url: '/some-other-place',
    resolve: {
      someOtherResolveObj: ['mainResolveObj', function (mainResolveObj) {
        console.log(mainResolveObj); //-> 'I am needed elsewhere!'. 
      }]
    }
  });
```

Kind of a bad example, but I take it you get the gist of it. Define the name of a higher level resolve object as a dependency to your lower level resolve and it'll wait for it to resolve first.

This is how we've solved preloading certain data before lower order resolve objects, aswell as authentication requirements (among other things).

Good luck.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; thanks. I wasn't aware mainResolveObj would be available to someOtherResolveObj.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that the resolves should chain, and I've hit many problems around this area.

However, they don't, so the solution I have come up with is to use my own promise stored in a service which you resolve when the data is complete. I have tried my best to edit your plunkr to work but to no avail. I am no longer hitting your errors though, so hopefully you can work from this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yi65ciQPu7lxjkFMBKLn?p=preview

**What it's doing:**

Store the config in a state alongside a new promise object

```
myapp.service('state', function($q) {
  this.load = $q.defer();
  this.config = {}
})
```

On your first resolve, store your config in this service and once ready resolve the new promise we created above.

```
myapp.factory('Config', function($http, $log, state) {
  return $http.get('example.json')
    .then(function (data) {
      angular.extend(state.config, data.data);
      state.load.resolve();
    });
});
```

The final and most important step is to not call our second the content of the childs resolve function until after our promise above is resolved:

```
myapp.factory('MyConfigDependingResource', function($log, state) {
  return state.load.promise.then(function() {
    if (!state.config.text) {
      $log.error('Config is uninitialized!');
    }
    else {
      // Do wonderful things
    }
    return
  });
});
```

The main thing you will need to be aware of is that the config is now stored in a state. There should be ways around this but this is how I've done it before.

Comment: I think they don't chain because of if each resolve requested data from the server you would want them to run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

While they cannot be chained, you can call one from another:

```
var resolve2 = ['$stateParams',function($stateParams){
  // do resolve 2 stuff
  ...
  return true;
}];

var resolve1 = ['$stateParams',function($stateParams){
  // do resolve 1 stuff
  ...
  // now do resolve2 stuff
  return $injector.invoke(resolve2,this,{$stateParams:$stateParams});
}];


$stateProvider.state("myState", {
  resolve: {
    resolve1: resolve1
  }
});
```